# How do I write (:)(.) on pointful form?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I have a hard time understanding what the function `(:)(.)` in haskell does. Could someone help me write it on pointful form, and explain step by step how to get there? The first step would be to expand the `(:)` so that we get `((.) :)`, but then I'm stuck.
It should be of type `[(b->c)->(a->b)->a->c]->[(b->c)->(a->b)->a->c]`, but that doesn't help me, just makes me even more confused.

Comment: `[(.)]` is the list containing the function `(.)`. `(:) (.)` is a function that takes a list and produces a list with `(.)` at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well we can first convert the `(:)` data constructor, and the function [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-46-) operator as a lambda expression:

```
(:) -> (\x y -> (x:y))
(.) -> (\f g t -> f (g t))
```

So that means that `(:)(.)` is short for:

```
(\x y -> (x:y)) (\f g t -> f (g t))
```

So now we can replace `x` with the lambda expression:

```
 \y -> (\f g t -> f (g t)) : y
```

So the function is equal to `((.) :)`: a partial "cons" where we still need to fill in the tail, and the head is the dot operator.

So the type is a list of functions with the same signature as the dot operator `[(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c]`.

If we thus for example take as argument `[]`, we have constructed a *singleton* list (a list with exactly one element): the dot operator.

Answer (score 5):

```
(:) (.)
```

Eta-expand:

```
\x -> (:) (.) x
```

Convert to infix notation:

```
\x -> (.) : x
```

I.e. `x` must be a list and we're prepending `(.)` to it (that's what `:` does: it prepends an element to a list).

`(.)` is a function, so `x` must be a list of functions.

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

, so `x` must have type

```
x   :: [(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c]
```